# Why does the JavaScript array operation [1,2,3,4][1,2] return 3?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am not able to understand why this JavaScript array is returning 3. What is the logic behind returning 3?

I just executed this in a developer's tool:

```
[1,2,3,4][1,2]
```

Comment: `[1,2,3,4]` is an array. In `[1,2]` `1,2` Comma operator causes the result as `2`. and `arr[2]` returns element at second index - **3**.

Comment: What did you expect it to be, and why?

Comment: What and where is thr row that returns 3??

Comment: @PreferenceBean by which keyword you searched it? i searched a lot but didnt came across that answer

Comment: @user2181397: I remembered it so only had to go into my profile, Answers section, sort by votes, and copy/paste the URL to the top one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Breakdown of `[1,2,3,4][1,2]`

1. `[1,2,3,4]`: A normal array of four elements
2. `1,2`: [Comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) returning the last operand. Thus, giving result as `2`
3. `arr[2]`: Accessing the element from array using [Bracket Notation/Property Accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors).

Thus the resulting equivalent statement will be `[1, 2, 3, 4][2]`.

---

This is equivalent to

```
var index = 1, 2; // Note the comma operator. This is same as `var index = 2;`
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

arr[index]; // arr[2] = 3
```

Comment: That's so weird. I never knew the comma operator did that. Thanks!